# How do I write an Elixir doctest to verify an empty MapSet

Tags: elixir, doctest, ex-unit

Just learning about doctests in Elixir and I'm trying to write an Elixir doctest to verify that a struct will contain two empty MapSets.

```
defstruct [:coordinates, :hit_coordinates]

@doc """
  Creates a new Island structure

  ## Examples

    iex> IslandsEngine.Island.new()
    %IslandsEngine.Island { coordinates: #MapSet<[]>, hit_coordinates: #MapSet<[]> }

"""
def new(), do:
  %Island{ coordinates: MapSet.new(), hit_coordinates: MapSet.new() }
```

When I run this using `mix test` I get the following error:

```
Compiling 1 file (.ex)

  1) doctest IslandsEngine.Island.new/0 (1) (IslandsEngine.IslandTest)
     test/islands_engine/island_test.exs:3
     Doctest did not compile, got: (TokenMissingError) lib/islands_engine/island.ex:19: missing terminator: } (for "{" starting at line 19)
     code: %IslandsEngine.Island { coordinates: #MapSet<[]>, hit_coordinates: #MapSet<[]> }
     stacktrace:
       lib/islands_engine/island.ex:19: IslandsEngine.Island (module)

.......

Finished in 0.1 seconds
6 doctests, 2 tests, 1 failure
```

Yet all runs fine in IEx session:

```
iex> IslandsEngine.Island.new()
%IslandsEngine.Island{coordinates: #MapSet<[]>, hit_coordinates: #MapSet<[]>}
iex>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have code constructing a valid answer instead of the textual representation in your doctest. So instead of:

```
%IslandsEngine.Island{coordinates: #MapSet<[]>, hit_coordinates: #MapSet<[]>}
```

Do:

```
%IslandsEngine.Island{coordinates: %MapSet{}, hit_coordinates: %MapSet{}}
```

I guess in this case the example has little value as a test, because it just replicates the code, but it might still be valid as documentation.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, your explanation makes sense and yes it's really more for a documentation example as well as a simple regression test.